# Get Second Point By First And Distance

Tags: javascript, distance, point

I'm building an online game, and using node and whatnot, anyway i'm not too keen on constant streams and streams of data just for animations, i've set up a way for it to animate client side and so on... but i found a problem, all i was doing was setting the new coordinates and telling all the clients to animate their character to that point, but if you refreshed the page, the player would be there instantly.

I have got a distance,speed of movement,time of movement,start and destination... i know where they started moving, i know where their destination is, i know when they started moving and at what speed, and in a linear fashion.

What i need to work out, is where the player is (whilst animating) at that specific time when other players join the game.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics

Or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed

the distance travelled can be calculated by rearranging the definition to d=v*t

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to *tween* the position. That involves creating a series of intermediate steps along the path between the current position and the updated one. This works best if you know the frequency of updates. You can choose these points linearly or use an [easing function](http://easings.net/) to smooth it out.

If you really are doing a physical simulation though, it'll probably look more natural if you take the physical model into consideration. I'd try the simple case first before seeing whether you need to go into more mathematically complex territory.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I see what you mean however that wasn't how the system worked.

The client would send an event to the server, saying where they currently were and what the destination was. This event is then relayed to all other clients where the effect is mirrored.